# Permutations and Combinations 2

Tags: permutations

The word ARGENTINA include the four consonants R,G,N,T and the vowels A,E,I
How many of the arrangements have a consonant at the beginning,then a vowel,then another consonant at the beginning,then a vowel,then another consonant,and so on alternately?

My attempted answer:

CVCVCVC

4!*3!
but textbook says its 720 arrangements

Comment: The word ARGENTINA has **9** letters (with two "A" and two "N")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can arrange the consonants in (5!/2!) ways and the vowels in (4!/2!) ways. Multiplying these gives 720